# Possible to create a query that sorts by day of week?

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to write a SQL query that sorts data set by **day of week starting from a specific day**?

For example, if today is Thursday, the results are sorted from THU-FRI-SAT-...-MON-TUE-WED.
If today is Tuesday, the results would be sorted from TUE-WED-THU-...-SAT-SUN-MON.

Days are stored as integers.

Comment: Well, the question has a "sqlite" tag so...

Comment: @ain, it was first a "sql" tag, then Flimzy commented, then I edited the tag.

Comment: Oh, sorry, when I saw the question it already had "sqlite" tag and I assumed that Flimzy didn't notice it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the day of the week stored into field `WD` where value 1 means MON, 2 means TUE etc and `SW` is the "start of the week" index (again 1:MON, 2:TUE,...) then something like

```
CASE WHEN WD < SW THEN WD + 7 ELSE WD END
```

should give you a value to order by. I don't use sqlite so I'm not sure can you put it right into the `ORDER BY` or do you have to use it as a field and then order by that field.

Comment: Yes, you can put a CASE in the ORDER BY with SQLite (I even checked).

Comment: @mu, where did you find this in the documentation? Would you be kind enough to give me a link?

Comment: @Sheldon: I don't have an authoritative reference for SQLite specifically but it is standard SQL. I tried it with SQLite to be sure though.

Comment: @Sheldon: Perhaps (3) in the [ORDER BY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) documentation applies: "if the ORDER BY expression is any other expression..."; a CASE certainly qualifies as an expression.

Answer (score 1):

in mysql:  `ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date,%w)`

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Microsoft databases suport this (not shure)
... `ORDER by DATENAME ( dw , table.datefield )`

Answer (score 1):

Check out DATEPART:

http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqldatepart.php