# How to order weekdays traversing Sunday (0) including partial weeks?

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

I'm reading opening hours for libraries from a database, so I get returned something like:

```
{
   "5":{ // library ID
      "4":{ // interval ID
         "statement":"",
         "start_date":"5th Jan 2015",
         "end_date":"1st Mar 2015",
         "hours":[
            {
               "day_of_week":"Sun",
               "opening_time":"12am",
               "closing_time":"12am",
               "is_closed":true,
               "open_24hrs":false
            },
            {
               "day_of_week":"Mon",
               "opening_time":"9am",
               "closing_time":"5pm",
               "is_closed":false,
               "open_24hrs":false
            },
            {
               "day_of_week":"Tue",
               "opening_time":"9am",
               "closing_time":"5pm",
               "is_closed":false,
               "open_24hrs":false
            },
```

for each "regular" opening hours and the same for each "variation", where the interval may be anything from one day to seven days. (here I've already preprocessed the day numbers to short day names). I'm getting the data from PostGreSQL via AJAX/PHP. My question is, how can I properly order the days for variations when the intervals may be anything from one day to several  weeks (but only hours for one week are stored for intervals one week or longer), and can begin at any day eg: Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon long weekend (in this case the day numbers are  5,6,0,1 and so come out ordered as Sun, Mon, Fri, Sat)?

My initial thoughts are:

- check if interval is a full week
- if not, check if Sunday is traversed
- if not, easily order by number
- if Sunday is traversed, get start day and order up to Sunday then
  reset to 0 (for Sunday) and continue to highest number before start
  day

But I'm wondering if this is all overkill and I can accomplish the same using an order by clause or similar, something like this: [Possible to create a query that sorts by day of week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622084/possible-to-create-a-query-that-sorts-by-day-of-week)
?

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would order it like so:

```
ORDER BY interval.start_date, hours.day_of_week, hours.opening_time
```

Comment: But isn't that going to give results like my long weekend example? Ie. 0,1,5,6 - Sun, Mon, Fri, Sat

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In that case, there is no way to know which `hours.day_of_week` should be the first date of the interval without converting each `hours.day_of_week` back to a calendar date. Are you able to change the schema to design this problem away?

Comment: Hi Daniel, the problem with converting each dow to a calendar date means I'd have to store a record for every date in each interval, even if the interval is for several weeks  (like the summer break). Good idea though to think back to the schema - perhaps an "order" field with each hours record? Eg. day_num: 0,1,5,6 / dow: Sun, Mon, Fri, Sat / order: 3,4,1,2

Comment: I see what you mean. In your original problem statement, you said: "My question is, how can I properly order the days for variations when the intervals may be anything from one day to one week," - is that still valid? Or can a single interval cover an arbitrarily large number of days?

Comment: Ah yes sorry - a single interval can cover an arbitrarily large number of days - but only up to one week of hours is stored - I've updated the question to reflect this

Comment: Hi Daniel, retrospectively I've realised that the correct day order is specified by the database ids of the opening_hours table for each interval! So ordering by opening_hours.id gave me the ordering I needed. I will accept your answer as it was very helpful pointing me in the right direction and getting me to think about other possibilities.